# Equality of two different arrays

Tags: c, hash, openssl, sha

How can I compare the result in t2(hash value)

```
unsigned char t2[128];

SHA1(t1, strlen(t1),t2);
```

with another hash value `unsigned char t3[128];`  that I have as a 'string'( character sequence)?

Elementwise equality fails and weird symbols appear when printing t1

Answer (score 0):

Your question needs more clarification. However,

`Elementwise equality fails and weird symbols appear when printing t1`

From this line, it appears that the array `t1` is not properly `NULL` terminated, i.e., not qualified to be used as a `string`.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that all your `tx` arrays are hash values: looking at `SHA1` manpage there is no information about a NULL-terminating byte or character encoding. It just about `bytes` so I guess you shouldn't try to print it as a string (i.e. with `%s`).

```
// print t1 bytes
for(size_t i=0; i<128; i++)
{
    printf("0x%2X ", t1[i]);
}
```

AND, `strlen` is likely to return garbage, use explicit length instead:

```
SHA1(t1, 128, t2);
```

So to compare your hash values (of same length) you can use :

```
int res = memcmp(t2, t3, 128);
```

Or:

```
for(size_t i=0; i<128; i++)
{
    if(t2[i] != t3[i])
    {
        printf("Mismatch at index %zu\n", i);
        break;
    }
}
```